How to Extend Token Lifetime in Self-Hosted Bitwarden
I’m using a self-hosted Bitwarden server. The email with the token arrives with a delay, and by the time the user enters the token, it’s already expired. How can I extend the token's lifetime? Should I adjust settings in Nginx, Bitwarden’s configuration files, or elsewhere?
This version keeps the request clear, and ensures that you're asking for specific information related to your server setup and the token expiration issue.

To extend the token lifetime in a self-hosted Bitwarden installation, modify the configuration file with the following settings:
yamlCopyglobalSettings__security__tokenLifetimeInHours: 24
globalSettings__security__identityTokenLifetimeInHours: 24

These settings should be added to your config.yml or globalSettings.json (depending on your installation method). After modifying then save the file and restart the server.
If there are still delays, you can check email server configuration, logs ot even NTP synchronization
